# Proper use of for and if statements in Java/Android

Tags: java, android

I have an two arrays, one is cityUSA[i] and one is decimalUSA[i].  Each has over 1500 entries, cityUSA[100] goes with decimalUSA[100] and so on.  I find the city people are in via location services in Android and then I compare it to the list of cities I have in the cityUSA[i] array.  I then search for a match and use the i of the match to find the related value of decimalUSA[i] in that array.  Here is the code:

loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(rate.this, Locale.ENGLISH);

```
        try {
              List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);

              TextView rateText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.taxRate);
              TextView locationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.taxLocation);

              if(addresses != null) {
               Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
               String city = returnedAddress.getLocality();
               locationText.setText(city);

                int i;
                for (i = 0; i  <= cityUSA.length; i++){
                    if (cityUSA[i] == city) {
                    String PrecentString = decimalRate[i];
                    rateText.setText(PrecentString);
                    break;
                    }
                }


              }
              else{
                  locationText.setText("No City returned!");
                  rateText.setText("No Rate returned!");
              }


             } 


              catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
              TextView locationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Rate);
              locationText.setText("Cannot get Location!");
             }
```

The application bombs out when I try to run it.  If I remove the for statment:

```
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i  <= cityUSA.length; i++){
                    if (cityUSA[i] == city) {
                    String PrecentString = decimalRate[i];
                    rateText.setText(PrecentString);
                    break;
                    }
                }
```

It does not bomb out, but then again it does not perform the search either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As an additional comment, try to keep with the Java naming conventions. I see that you have a String named "PrecentString" (sic). Sticking with naming conventions would yield "percentString". Just a quick tip (useful for when others read your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you aren't, I see one immediate error in that you're comparing two strings with the "==" operator:

```
if(cityUSA[i]==city)
```

Instead, to check the contents of each string (and whether they are equal):

```
if(cityUSA[i].equals(city))
```

Also, the <= in the for loop will cause an off by one error. Keep it just as a "<".

Also, what do you mean by "bomb out"? It would be helpful if you gave a specific exception being thrown and on what line.

Comment: As Chris Schaffer also said, you may use equalsIgnoreCase() to ignore case differences (i.e. New York vs. new york).

Comment: Also, the reason why you must use "equals()" and not "==" is because "==" will check to see if cityUSA[i] and city reside in the same memory location (i.e. they are the same object). "==" does not check to see if the contents of cityUSA[i] and city are the same.

Comment: The bombing out was no doubt an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` due to the use of `<=` as you pointed out.

Comment: I meant by bombing out that the app closed unexpectedly on the device.  At any rate your suggestions solved the problem and it runs fine now.  Too much programming in javaScript comparing real numbers I guess.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Haha it's all good. Then just check the green arrow to close the question if it's been solved. :-) (You an actually check anyone's answers, they all say the same thing really haha.)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating one too many times (of course, this will only happen if the city doesn't exist in the array); Should be `for (i = 0; i < cityUSA.length; i++){`.

As to why you may not find the city in the array, you may have a case-sensitivity issue.  Maybe try `if (cityUSA[i].equalsIgnoreCase(city)){` instead.

Comment: Thank you Chris yours and Vinay's comments solved my problem and now the app is running perfectly.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, comparing two string objects using `==` checks whether they are the same object, not whether they contain the same string.  You should compare strings with `.equals()`.

Secondly, your array index will go out of bounds if the match fails (which, because of the above, it probably will).  Valid indices in `cityUSA` are 1 to `cityUSA.length-1`, whereas the `for` loop will continue to `cityUSA.length`.

Thirdly, having two codependent arrays in this way is not great design: it ought to be possible to find an Object-oriented pattern suitable to your needs.